# Java, genetic algorithm traveling salesman issue

Tags: java, arraylist, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

Working on project for class having some issues during the crossover (I understand the issues I'll face later in the assignment, but it's how the professor asked) my chromosome 1 and 2 are reporting as the same thing.

```
randomNum = rand.nextInt(3);
Chromosome chromosome2 = topTen.remove(randomNum);
System.out.print(chromosome2 + "\n");
index = generation.indexOf(chromosome2);
generation.remove(index);
```

here is the rest of the code

```
public Chromosome tsp(int population, int num_generations) {    

    //Random Seed
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum;

    //Generate inital population
    ArrayList<Chromosome> generation = new ArrayList<Chromosome>();
    for (int i = 0; i < population; i++) {

        //Clone original
        ArrayList<Vertex> genes = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
        for (Vertex v: vertex_list) {
            genes.add(new Vertex(v.toString()));
        }

        //Mix genes
        for (int j = genes.size() - 1; j > 1; j--) {
            randomNum = rand.nextInt(j) + 1;
            Vertex removed = genes.remove(randomNum);
            genes.add(removed);
        }

        genes.add(genes.get(0)); //Add start gene to end
        int score = checkScore(genes); //Check distance
        Chromosome chromosome = new Chromosome(genes, score); //Create chromosome
        generation.add(chromosome); //Add chromosome to generation list
    }

    //Generation Loop
    for (int i = 0; i < num_generations; i++) {
        ArrayList<Chromosome> newGen = new ArrayList<Chromosome>(); //Holds new generation
        Collections.sort(generation); //Sort generation

        //Keep top 10 from previous generation
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            Chromosome best = generation.remove(j);
            newGen.add(best);
        }

        //Crossover the rest of the generation
        while(!generation.isEmpty()) {

            //Pick Ten Randomly
            ArrayList<Chromosome> topTen = new ArrayList<Chromosome>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                randomNum = rand.nextInt(generation.size());
                topTen.add(generation.get(randomNum));
            }

            //Sort Those 10
            Collections.sort(topTen);

            //Get first chromosome
            randomNum = rand.nextInt(4);
            Chromosome chromosome1 = topTen.remove(randomNum);
        System.out.print(chromosome1 + "\n");
            int index = generation.indexOf(chromosome1);
            generation.remove(index); //remove extra

            //Get second chromosome
            randomNum = rand.nextInt(3);
            Chromosome chromosome2 = topTen.remove(randomNum);
        System.out.print(chromosome2 + "\n");
            index = generation.indexOf(chromosome2);
            generation.remove(index); //remove extra

        }
    }

    return generation.get(0);
}
```

Chromosome class constructor

```
public Chromosome(ArrayList<Vertex> genes, int score) {
    this.genes = genes;
    this.score = score;
}
```

Comment: <code>genes.add(genes.get(0)); //Add start gene to end
    int score = checkScore(genes); //Check distance
    Chromosome chromosome = new Chromosome(genes, score); //Create chromosome
    generation.add(chromosome); //Add chromosome to generation list
<code>
having some issues using the formatting here..

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Instead you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25905107/edit) your question.

Comment: edit your post instead of writing comments - **please**

Comment: Alright I edited the post. I'll keep that in mind for future post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem. Was adding duplicate chromosomes during the random generation of 10 chromosomes. Just need to make them unique.